# Hash is not saving date as values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, type-conversion, hash

I have a hash in Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.8:

```
   important_dates = params[:important_dates]
   important_dates =#> 
    {"third_test"=>"July 11, 2014", "fourth_test"=>"August 08, 2014", "second_test"=>"June 13, 2014", "sixth_test"=>"August 05, 2014"}
```

The dates are coming from a `calendar_select_date_tag` in Rails to which I am passing a date object, but in the params I am getting a string always when I try doing this:

```
    new_dates = important_dates.each_value{|r| r.to_date}        
    new_dates[:fourth_test].class.inspect #=> String
```

I have been on this for hours now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new_dates = Hash[important_dates.map{|k,v| [k, v.to_date]}]
```

Or if you're using Ruby 2.0 or higher:

```
new_dates = important_dates.map{|k,v| [k, v.to_date]}.to_h
```

---

UPDATE: Why your answer is not working:

`each_value` is always returning the initial hash it iterates over and it drops block return values. Note, for example:

```
h = {a: 'foo', b: 'bar'}
h.each_value {|v| v.upcase }     #=> upcase creates a new string object
h                                #=> {a: 'foo', b: 'bar'}
```

However, if the value is mutable, you can try altering it during iteration:

```
h = {a: 'foo', b: 'bar'}
h.each_value {|v| v.upcase! }     #=> upcase! alters existing string object
h                                #=> {a: 'FOO', b: 'BAR'}
```

new_dates = important_dates.each_value{|r| r.to_date}

Since however you want to change a string object into a date object, there is absolutely no way of doing this using `each_value`.

Comment: It is explained in @Vimsha answer. `each_value` similarly to `each` returns an object it iterates over. Your block is not changing any of the values - it is creating a new object based on the value adn then it is not assigning it anywhere so it's lost.